# Can't connect to Internet and isn't the problem?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, connection

I've seen people having the same problem as me, although when they went to the Network parameters they were able to disable airplane mode and/or turn on the wireless setting, but I am not... When I try to turn it on, even though airplane mode is deactivated (which it enables right after I close the parameters window) it just turns back off right after. I tried `rfkill unblock all` or `sudo rfkill unblock wifi` but when it asks me for my password it just doesn't do anything and I'm really wondering why. I tried to restart my laptop, but it didn't help.

Maybe it's just a bug, and I have to wait for the newer version but what can I do if I can't download it from the Internet?

Comment: Show us the output of the command "lspci" if your wireless adapter is in a pci port, or "lsusb" if it's connected via usb.

Comment: @marie-pierre when it ask for your password, you should enter your password. If you don't know/have password ask to the person that installed the system. Also, add to your question `nm-tool` and `rfkill list` outputs.